# Using JWT with Azure Functions (WITHOUT using Active Directory) in nodejs javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure-functions

I need a solution for authenticating azure function endpoints with node js and javascript without using azure active directory and to know what are the possible ways to authenticate the azure function endpoints..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Microsoft provided multiple security options to fully secure our function endpoints along with the Azure Active Directory Authentication but we can use one of the following options:**

1. App Service Authentication Authentication/Authorization using AAD
2. **Azure API Management** provides a different API security options for incoming requests that you can configure your function app to accept requests only from the IP address of your APIM instance or specify the required access level IPs.
3. You can deploy your function app in an isolated app service environment which lets you configure the private DNS Zone and an application gateway acts as Firewall.
4. Azure Front Door is also one of the option to secure the endpoint of HTTP requests.

To know more information on the above options, refer these [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/serverless-quest/functions-app-security#secure-http-endpoints-for-development-testing-and-production) and [MS Doc2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-http-webhook-trigger?tabs=csharp#secure-an-http-endpoint-in-production).

Comment: As am using passport local with express session in my nodejs express web api how ro migrate these authentication and authorisation in serverless azure function???

Comment: There are few articles written to migrate to Azure from passport-local strategies. Please refer [passport-outh2 to Azure], [passport-azure-authentication](http://www.passportjs.org/packages/passport-azure-ad/) and [Js Passport Azure Authentication](https://www.ozkary.com/2016/11/nodejs-passport-azure-ad-authentication.html).

Comment: but still i cant find a solution coz in my case express plays a major role if i move on with azure functions i need to face isses with express funtionalites mainly middleware... which was used for authentication

Comment: authentication without azure active directory